# Caching multilingual Template

Tags: php, oop, caching, apc

I have a class called language.php in my environment which handles the language detection and includes the proper language file with all it's variables.

When a template is not cached already, i cache it via **APC** and sent the cache entry to the visitor.

But now when i try to make my environment multilingual, and i change my languages from **en-US** to **de-DE** and then ***back to en-US*** i still get the cached **de-DE** template.

Are there any intelligent approaches to this problem that i can work with and elaborate?

**EDIT:**
My parsing/caching function: http://pastebin.com/PpHJ14Wv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should handle the template as 2 different templates (or as many languages that you are going to support). Instead of caching a template.html, for instance, you could cache a template-en.html and a template-de.html.

And use the url (example.com/en or example.com/de) or a $_SESSION['lang'] variable or something like that, in order to load the proper cached template.

**EDIT**

like so:

```
public function parseTemplate($requestedTemplate, $lang)
{
    $template = $requestedTemplate . '-' . $lang;
    $filename = $this->templateDir . $template . '.php';

    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! - Sounds like a great attempt for solving my issue. Will try it later and then give feedback.